# Is it possible to create a load balancer in gcp that works without instance groups in a regional scope?

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-load-balancer

the problem is I have 3 virtual machines with the same source images in three diferent zones in a region. I can't put them in a MIG because each of them has to attach to a specific persistent disk and according that I researched, I have no control of which VM in the MIG will be attached to which persistent disk (please correct me if I´m wrong). I explored the unmanaged instance group option too, but only has zonal scope. Is there any way to create a load balancer that works with my VMs or I have to create another solution (ex. NGINX)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution in my case was using a dedicated vm, intalling nginx as a load balancer and creating static ips to each vm in the group. I couldn't implement managed or unmanaged instance groups and managed load balancer.

That worked fine but another solution found in quicklabs was adding all intances in a "instance pool", maybe in the future I will implement that solution.

Comment: just for the record: by replacing load balancer with a single nginx you bring the SLA of your whole setup down to 99.5%.

Comment: That´s true, it was a non-sense solution from my side, but you know: client-requirements .... :/

Answer (score 3):

You have two options.

Create an Unmanaged Instance Group. This allows you to set up your VM instances as you want. You can create multiple instance groups for each region.

[Creating groups of unmanaged instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-unmanaged-instances)

Use a Network Endpoint Group. This supports specifying backends based upon the Compute Engine VM instance's internal IP address. You can specify other methods such as an Internet address.

[Network endpoint groups overview](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs)

Comment: unfortunately unmanaged instance groups has only zonal scope, same case with the no-exposed NEGs

Comment: @PegaChucho 1) I provided two options in my answer. 2) As I mentioned in my answer you can create more than one unmanaged instance group. You can also use NEGs. 3) In both cases must configure those features correctly.

Comment: I know it was already implemented and done, but for the record: UMIGs are zonal, so you create one for each zone, group them in a regional backend service and attach BES as the target to a forwarding rule. Now available for both ILB and ELB.